# How can I show the browser bookmarks using a button?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How can I show the browser bookmarks when I click on show bookmarks button that I am creating on my JavaScript application? Thanks in advance.

I created a show bookmarks button and my ideal outcome is it should open the browser bookmarks window. The bookmark/favorite shortcut for edge browser is ctrl+shift+o.

Comment: It is most likely not possible to do what you are asking. The browser would need to provide an API to do this with JavaScript, and I don't know of any of the major browsers that do this.

Rather, let us know what your intent is. Do you want to add your web app as a bookmark in the user's browser? There are other ways to get the user to do that, like a bookmarklet that they drag-and-drop themselves.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No, I am creating a basic web page where i created a button called show bookmarks. When I click on that it should open the bookmark/favorites window. Instead of opening the bookmark window manually using the edge browser shortcut CTRL+SHiFT+O, i want to open the window using the button that i created.